# Angular - is FormController overridden by ng-controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm reading the Angular docs for [ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form), and it says

> form
>   - directive in module ng Directive that instantiates FormController.

Sounds good.  When I look at the [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#example), however, it shows something like this:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
```

Is the `ngController`-specified `FormController` the same as the one that is automatically instantiated by the form?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different controllers.

Your controller declared via `ng-controller` allows you to bind data to your controller's scope, or the form object in your controller directly.

HTML:

```
{{userType}}
<input ng-model="myForm.userType" />
```

Controller:

```
$scope.userType = 'guest';
$scope.myForm.userType = 'guest';
```

[FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) controls the state of the form via $isDirty, $setPristine, etc. methods and maintains your form's behavior for you without you needing to do so.

HTML:

```
{{myForm.$isDirty()}}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.myForm.$setPristine();
```

Note that in the first instance of the documentation, userType is referenced directly since it lives on the scope of whatever controller is bound by `ng-controller`.  In the second instance, we are reference the scope of the form object itself, `myForm`, which is bound to your controller scope automatically behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, look in the docs again :) It's just a mock data controller:

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.userType = 'guest';
  }]);
```